# Using Refs With Objects Stored In Tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ref

I'm trying to use refs to link objects between tables. Something like the following.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TYP_REFT AS OBJECT 
(A NUMBER, B NUMBER);
/
CREATE TABLE REFTT
(
  ref_id number,
  my_reft typ_reft
)
/
CREATE TABLE REFTAB
(ID    REF    TYP_REFT);
/
INSERT INTO REFTT VALUES (typ_reft(1,2));
/
INSERT INTO REFTAB
SELECT REF(T.my_reft) FROM REFTT T
/
SELECT * FROM REFTAB;
```

This doesn't work though. Giving me the error

```
Error starting at line : 18 in command -
INSERT INTO REFTAB
SELECT REF(T.my_reft) FROM REFTT T
Error at Command Line : 19 Column : 12
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "T"."MY_REFT": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

It works fine if the table REFTT is made by saying

```
CREATE TABLE REFTT OF TYP_REFT
```

But since I'd like to store other information in the table besides just the object, it's a little problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[REF reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions145.htm#SQLRF006)

REF takes as its argument a table alias associated with a row of an object table.

```
CREATE TABLE REFTT OF TYP_REFT
```

If you create your REFTT table of TYPE_REFT, then your code would work, as you stated.   You can store other information in REFTAB.

```
CREATE TABLE REFTAB
(ID    REF    TYP_REFT,
 MOREINFO VARCHAR2(20));


INSERT INTO REFTAB
  SELECT REF(T), 'BIGTIME'
    FROM REFTT T;
```